# Show that if $f(\partial D) \subset \partial D$ then $f(D) \subset D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f $ an analytic function in a domain which contains properly the unit disk $D = \{ z \text{ : } |z|\leq 1 \}$ Show that if $f(\partial D) \subset \partial D$ then $f(D) \subset D$

I was trying to use that analytics functions reach its maximum in the boundary of a closed arc, I mean how $f(\partial D) \subset \partial D$ then $|f(z)|=1 $ $\forall z \in \partial D$ then $|f(z')| \leq 1$ for $z'\in D$ that implies that $f(D)\subset  \partial D \subset D$ but I don't know if its right

Comment: sorry I think I made a double post, I just delete the other

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: The proof is fine. Be careful that it is not true the last chain of inclusions: $f(D)\not \subseteq \partial D$. otherwise, from your proof, you can directly conclude that $f(D)\subseteq D$

Comment: Lucas is correct. You cannot write $f(D)\subseteq \partial D$. But you can directly say $f(D)\subseteq D$ as $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in D$ by the maximum modulus principle.